# How best to name sets in Python?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, set, discrete-mathematics

I'm very acquainted to Discrete Mathematics concepts in which, as you may know, sets must be specified with a single uppercase letter **in range** (A-Z). I was wondering if this rule or convention should be taken into account when declaring sets in Python or when coding. I have a point of view where it totally adds up but I also have a point of view where it doesn't.

People are used to implement the same data structures over and over. Most programmers would think an array or lists, dictionaries and sets are the same thing. They are sets in a way but they're obviously different on what you can achieve with each of them and as a result you have different catalogs of built-in functions to deal with. That's why I'd like *sets* to stand out  in coding and stick to the mathematical convention, *at least in Python*.

I think if I bump into someone else's code and I find these sort of declarations, it would make sense to me and it'd say something positive about the coder. I'd like to stick to the mathematical concept even when programming but just wanted to know what your thoughts or opinions might be on this matter.

**When Math meets Code, which conventions survive?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that variable names should start with lowercase letters. This should be followed in your code unless you want to write code counter to the conventions recommended by the community. Lots of people don't follow it, unfortunately, mostly because of ignorance or previous conventions they've learned and followed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it is worth, I also follow the idioms of the programming language in question.  So I would use the Python naming conventions even for mathematical concepts.  It is far more likely that someone reading Python code will expect and recognize the standard naming conventions.  From the point of view of a discrete mathematician, you see `set` as a very important data type worthy of distinguishing.  As a Python programmer, they are just another tool in the toolbox to me - meant to be used whenever I need an unordered collection of unique instances.